# Parse.com MealSpotting tutorial onitemclicklistener not working

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, onclicklistener

i'm having some trouble getting the onclicklistener to work with a customadapter from parse.com's mealspotting android app. When I try clicking on an item in the list nothing happens in the logcat (except for the standard "can't load audio" or whatever), i'm pretty sure i need to attach something to the adapter but i haven't found a way to implement that with parse's APIs. When a list item is clicked I want it to show the DetailViews class activity by the way.

This is where i'm trying to implement the onclicklistener

> package com.parse.mealspotting;
>
> ```
> import java.util.Arrays;
>
> import android.content.Context;
>
> import android.util.Log;
>
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.AdapterView;
> import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
>
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.parse.GetDataCallback;
> import com.parse.ParseException;
> import com.parse.ParseFile;
> import com.parse.ParseImageView;
> import com.parse.ParseObject;
> import com.parse.ParseQuery;
> import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
>
>
>
>
> public class MealSpottingViewYay extends ParseQueryAdapter<Meal> implements OnItemClickListener {
>
>
>   private ParseQueryAdapter<Meal> posts;
>   private static final String TAG = "MealSpottingViewYay";   
>
>
>
>   public MealSpottingViewYay(Context context) {
>       super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Meal>() {
>           public ParseQuery<Meal> create() {
>               // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
>               // only top-rated meals.
>               ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Meal");
>               return query;
>
>           }
>       });
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public View getItemView(Meal meal, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
>
>
>       if (v == null) {
>           v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.main_list_view, null);
>       }
>
>       super.getItemView(meal, v, parent);
>
>       ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
>       ParseFile photoFile = meal.getParseFile("photo");
>       if (photoFile != null) {
>           mealImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
>           mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
>               @Override
>               public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
>                   // nothing to do
>
>
>
>               }});
>
>       }
>
>       TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
>       titleTextView.setText(meal.getTitle());
>       TextView ratingTextView = (TextView) v
>               .findViewById(R.id.favorite_meal_rating);
>       ratingTextView.setText(meal.getRating());
>       return v;       
>   }
>
>
>   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>             int position, long id) {
>             Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick");
>
>         ParseObject parseObject = posts.getItem(position);
>
>         // Use the parseobject here
>         Context context = getContext();
>         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
>         toast.show();
>
>
>         } 
>     }
> ```

and this is my mainactivity class

> ```
> package com.parse.mealspotting;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.app.ListActivity;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.Menu;
> import android.view.MenuItem;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.AdapterView;
> import android.widget.ListView;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
>
> import com.parse.ParseObject;
> import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
>
> public class MealListActivity extends ListActivity {
>
>   private MealSpottingViewYay mainAdapter;
>   private FavoriteMealAdapter22 favoritesAdapter;
>
>
>   @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       getListView().setClickable(false);
>
>       mainAdapter = new MealSpottingViewYay(this);
>
>
>       // There's probably a better way to do this
>       if (mainAdapter != null){
>           updateMealList();
>       }
>
>       // Subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
>       favoritesAdapter = new FavoriteMealAdapter22(this);
>
>
>
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_meal_list, menu);
>       return true;
>   }
>
>   /*
>    * Posting meals and refreshing the list will be controlled from the Action
>    * Bar.
>    */
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>       switch (item.getItemId()) {
>
>       case R.id.action_refresh: {
>           updateMealList();
>           break;
>       }
>
>       case R.id.action_favorites: {
>           showFavorites();
>           break;
>       }
>
>       case R.id.action_new: {
>           newMeal();
>           break;
>       }
>       }
>       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>   }
>
>   private void updateMealList() {
>       mainAdapter.loadObjects();
>       setListAdapter(mainAdapter);
>   }
>
>   private void showFavorites() {
>       favoritesAdapter.loadObjects();
>       setListAdapter(favoritesAdapter);
>   }
>
>   private void newMeal() {
>       Intent i = new Intent(this, NewMealActivity.class);
>       startActivityForResult(i, 0);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
>           // If a new post has been added, update
>           // the list of posts
>           updateMealList();
>       }
>   }
>
>
> }
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a click listener to your listview. Try this `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(mainAdapter)` as your adapter has implemented an `onItemClickListener`interface.

Comment: That got the onclicklistener working, it crashes when clicked but that shouldn't be too much of a problem to clear up. Thanks a lot though! Can't believe the answer was that simple.